# Typescript generics validate all keys of keyof are specified

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a helper functions that wraps some object and modifies all of its keys depending on it being a query or a mutation function.

I want to write a typescript declaration that ensures that all keys of the object are specified in either of the two parameters.

What I currently have is:

```js
function createService<
    T,
    Q extends keyof T,
    M extends Exclude<keyof T, Q>,
>(obj: T, queries: readonly Q[], mutations: readonly M[]) {}
```

This does validates that a key is only in one of the two params,
but I can not figure out how to validate that all keys exist.

Example usage:

```js
interface Test {
  a: () => void;
  b: () => void;
}
const obj: Test = { a: () => {}, b: () => {} };

createService(obj, ["a"], ["b"]); // OK
createService(obj, ["a", "b"], []); // OK

createService(obj, ["a", "b"], ["b"]); // Error, "b" is set twice
createService(obj, ["a"], []); // No Error but should be because "b" is not set
createService(obj, [], ["b"]); // No Error but should be because "a" is not set
```

I tried something like the following: but this does not compile.

```js
function createService<
    T,
    Q extends keyof T,
    M extends Exclude<keyof T, Q>,
    CHECK extends never = Exclude<keyof T, Q | M>, // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
>(obj: T, queries: readonly Q[], mutations: readonly M[]) {}
```

[Playground link to example code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAigJwKYEMYYMoZoBucUGAPMMtcgCoA0VNAishgB64QAmAzsgGsMATwQg6jGsgCybThh78AouygAbMNwpDR4hsmYA+RoYAUCAEYArAFwTkARzCE4GXncxZuSNcIMBtAF16ZABbMBgcRAh3ZE9vCF8ZIIBKZABvAF9gHPBoeCRUT1wCYlIMACZKKQYmalYOLj5BETEJOpk5JuVVDS1yHTb9I0kaAGEACSUxgGkuhWaIDCJCZABeZBV1TW1WvRDWAB8ZY2AzS1t7Jxc3D2wEpOYgkPDIgpi7rx8-aVSM7JycAguDQICwZDobhgGSYWDspjSa0MyCICDg3AA3EwLPDEcjUeisdkoEheNCLnZaFD1hlkHDkAj1sisiEcQy8f9kJkscB0NgSoQSGRzNYQv4AERYcXBZASizSlIY5AAemVyAA8jNecV8ILyiKrGLJeKQuL5TLUkrVRqtdr+bqysKLkapabzUbzYqVWqlGg0Ag0MgzeLkHB+LwMNCYAB3cp2nAOoUYA0u6ViwJe60AOQQmz9AeQFgiyF4AAsEGA1NxCxga1AsGAI0H5aH+BAENCIzBgEA)

Is this even possible to validate in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you could take is add a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `T` as well, so that any properties for keys other than `Q` or `M` are effectively prohibited (using [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type):

```
function createService<
    T extends Record<Exclude<keyof T, Q | M>, never>,
    Q extends keyof T,
    M extends Exclude<keyof T, Q>
>(obj: T, queries: readonly Q[], mutations: readonly M[]) { }


interface Test {
    a: () => void;
    b: () => void;
}
const obj: Test = { a: () => { }, b: () => { } };
    
createService(obj, ["a"], ["b"]); // OK
createService(obj, ["a", "b"], []); // OK

createService(obj, ["a", "b"], ["b"]); // Error
createService(obj, ["a"], []); // Error
createService(obj, [], ["b"]); // Error
```

That now works as desired.

Note that this doesn't account for every possible circumstance.  TypeScript doesn't natively represent the concept of *exhaustive arrays*.  An array of type `(T1 | T2 | T3)[]` is not guaranteed to have elements of each of type `T1`, `T2`, and `T3`. It's not guaranteed to have any elements at all.  So someone *could* do this:

```
const aArr: "a"[] = [];
const bArr: "b"[] = [];
createService(obj, aArr, bArr);
```

---

Presumably that isn't a use case you're concerned about.  If it is, then the only possible approach would be to enumerate every possible acceptable [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) input:

```
type AllPossiblePartialTuples<T, U = T> =
    [T] extends [never] ? readonly [] : T extends any ?
    readonly [T, ...AllPossiblePartialTuples<Exclude<U, T>>] | 
    AllPossiblePartialTuples<Exclude<U, T>>
    : never;

type AllPossibleTuples<T, U = T> =
    [T] extends [never] ? readonly [] : T extends any ?
    readonly [T, ...AllPossibleTuples<Exclude<U, T>>] : never;

declare function createService<
    T extends object,
    const Q extends AllPossiblePartialTuples<keyof T>
>(
    obj: T,
    queries: Q,
    mutations: AllPossibleTuples<
        Exclude<keyof T, Q extends readonly (infer V)[] ? V : never>
    >
): void;

const obj: Test = { a: () => { }, b: () => { } };

createService(obj, ["a"], ["b"]); // OK
createService(obj, ["a", "b"], []); // OK

createService(obj, ["a", "b"], ["b"]); // Error
createService(obj, ["a"], []); // Error
createService(obj, [], ["b"]); // Error
```

But that's only plausible if `T` has a small number of keys.  For even a modest number of keys, the union of all possible permutations of those keys is very large, and will cause either performance problems or compiler errors about complexity limits or both:

```
// okay-ish
createService(
    { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5 },
    ['a', 'c', 'e'],
    ['b', 'd', 'f']
);

//  COMPILER EATS UP CPU RESOURCES
createService(
    { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h:7},
    ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g'],
    ['b', 'd', 'f', 'h']
);

// ☠☠ EVENTUALLY ISSUES AN ERROR ABOUT COMPLEXITY
createService(
    { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h:7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10},
    ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'k'],
    ['b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j']
);
```

So I'd probably suggest you go with the first approach unless you have a very particular use case.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQZTSgNxgjQB4AoRKxAFUTQA9swATAZ0QCU0I4UXSAUQYQANiBZkA1mgCecYLQA0iAIqIAPogCyAPhVg0BfPsrV1jZu0Qz5imkrNVt9JmlYdhYidLkLlarrkugAUcABGAFYAXAEAjiD4MGhssegYLAiismoA2gC6KgC2IFBY8GCpiOmZYNk6BQCUiADeiAC+5OQwYNgowBgktClQrU6IGLEhzQC8uogEcDAsANzj4VOz84vLa528laMRMcNsozOtE5uIc5ftKhuI0zfzbe0da+SomNh4hMRoMJRFS5ABEGFBhUQYPCkMaK0QAHpEYgAPIAaS+6V++CIJCBkRB4NBKlBsKhTQRyLRmKxP1wuIBBKJENJ5KJ5PhSJRghQKD4dKwDP++OOLMhIPyXOpvP5KEFOJFgLF0IpZLhVJ5fIFXwQZwmAEE+bFiQUbqq1gd9eEjSgTbCzRcCpbscK8crgYa+Q9bfCumAMEUUgAHQZoRAAIRgAHMAKpgCpjcZQWTB8MG0SiAAKcDYbBg4VEaCzGBQsAwohoIGDRbYpAciFj5po8xm42o0Jo+VcVg4uUMxhQ3YA-NVMLV6mbYnRLO5rBgwDlh+3qDUsjlcg2AHQ7jPZ3P5wvF0vlyvV2tCETiSSkWMqFu6btaFdUPc5vMFoslsswCtVmspJe3g3netC6EEHYdrEA74J8HYpmmiBvgen5oP+F4Nk2FwtjcL6dt2s4eNCMFDogo5rnUG7dtOPZzhwC5LnhFGTtuu6Zu+h5FuhgFeNeZCgQ+1GICRcHUJIYiluGoCQLACDIK6fzuhQkHUDObhEccPBQI4KlUFaowWOp1jIR+R7fqe3F1rY-gtuMoR4cc046bpCRJCksSqM5KklGUsmVLEJmcWh56AXhHa8T4pDWfYKiGb2Y4ZOuTw9MA+CIAAao0ZqjuliDQUYJh4RB1CNLEOyrF0Hb6YgjmnOclyTE8Wx3A81y3G8HyVdQ3xCopTIqmCEJqpymo0uMPWKu6zLQsSbISqq0oohiXV6QpjKip6g0kog6rDRq3KILKApVWtSrTVtFJSqNR3yid9J9RthKqhy+0ytq8rjNScBSBgsgALQwGwAAW42nVNeFtI1AAMrWIAAjCoECxAATCoLCxAAzCoaCxAALCowCxAArB0XmQbkADkGAUyoFMQDTiAU2gFOFHhlPhAzFMsJzwAs+MfqfSigC8G4ApLtC4A3Tui4gADCqLaFmACSAAygicIdBo0DgjZZjLWZNpwgg4KisacNLhug-d62AhDVyIDDiCPAjyAo2jmPY3jBPEyo0axAAbCoQPRAA7PcbNU5z9O08ztPRizZMduznPc7TvO00DfMdgLHaIgAVILiCAARkosS6LBeHelggAHI0LGBpK0rACaiAKzgOCxobSGV4dnCcKiasGhGxt0LL8sqwAGgrNANxbvVWyENvQ7DTtI4gqOIOjiBY-QHuIITiBE97fsB8HKgwLEAAcKgnAAnCoUixHDUOh7p0Lh7TkeM9HjOx7TMCc1Iccw4c1psnRmqdGbp1ppEDOJUERUHGDnRE5BOhAA)

Comment: Thanks! Your first example is simple and good enough

Answer (score 3):

You can define the type like this to check the unused keys

```js
type KeysLeft<T, Q extends keyof T> = Exclude<keyof T, Q>
type ArrayWithAtLeastOne<T> = [T, ...T[]]
type Mutations<T, Q extends keyof T> = KeysLeft<T, Q> extends never ? never[] : ArrayWithAtLeastOne<KeysLeft<T, Q>>

function createService<
  T,
  Q extends keyof T,
>(obj: T, queries: Array<Q>, mutations: Mutations<T, Q>) { }
```

But since it's generic this will cause an error:

```
createService<Test, 'a' | 'b'>(obj, ["a"], ["b"]); // OK
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#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)

---

A solution would be to use TypeScript's 5.0 [const type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters)

```js
type KeysLeft<T, Q extends keyof T> = Exclude<keyof T, Q>
type ArrayWithAtLeastOne<T> = [T, ...T[]]
type Mutations<T, Q extends keyof T> = KeysLeft<T, Q> extends never ? never[] : ArrayWithAtLeastOne<KeysLeft<T, Q>>

function createService<
  T,
  const Q extends readonly (keyof T)[],
>(obj: T, queries: Q, mutations: Mutations<T, Q[number]>) { }
```

[Updated playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Thanks but it does not completely work, it only validates the second parameter but e.g.
`createService(obj, [], ["b"]);` does not show an error

Answer (score 0):

COnsider this example:

```js
type IsNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true : false;


type TupleUnion<U extends PropertyKey, R extends any[] = [], Result = {
  [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U]> = IsNever<Result> extends true ? never[] : Result


const createService = <Obj,>(obj: Obj) => <
  Query extends keyof Obj,
  Queries extends Query[],
  Mutations extends TupleUnion<Exclude<keyof Obj, [...Queries][number]>>
>(
  queries: [...Queries],
  mutations: IsNever<Mutations> extends true ? never[] : Mutations
) => { }



interface Test {
  a: () => void;
  b: () => void;
}
const obj: Test = { a: () => { }, b: () => { } };

const service = createService(obj);

service(["a"], ['b']); // OK
service(["a", "b"], []); // OK
service([], ['a', 'b']) // ok

service(["a", "b"], ["b"]); // Error "b" is set twice
service(["a"], []); // error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NDAvxm)

`TupleUnion` creates a combination of allowed arrays from union.
`Exclude<keyof Obj, [...Queries][number]>` - excludes elements which are provided in `queries` argument

`createService` should be curried, because in order to use recursive `TupleUnion` provided object (`Test`) should be fully infered, otherwise TS will stuck with very deep recursive

`IsNever` inside `TupleUnion` - is used to handle infinity recursion.

In general, creating a tuple from union is a weak type solution because it will not allow you to use an object with many properties, there is a limit. But for this test case it works.

You can check my [blog](https://catchts.com/union-array) for more examples